# Which range of size fits my wheels with 265/55 R 19 tires?

Tags: tires

I am trying to find all terrain tires for my landcruiser with stock aluminum 19 inch wheels.

This is what it says on the side:
[image]

I want all terrain tires again, but can't find anything on the german sites I look at. Many sites have 0 results for this size, some have one or two options from brands I have never heard of.

Is there some flexibility here? Can I get tires with different parameters or does it have to be exactly this?

I am based in EU and can't find anything in German language sites.

I prefer buying online because I can read about the tire and save the 20% VAT when ordering from other EU country.

Also very confusing, some have the right size, rated mud and snow but are classified as summer tires? How can this be? Am I not allowed to drive these in the winter? I thought AT means all season too.

[image]

Comment: Have you asked in a tyre shop? You don't have to buy.

Comment: @WeatherVane good idea perhaps I thought maybe they won’t tell me unless I also buy from them. But ofc I will do other services there so why not.

Comment: Ask them for the tyre you want. They either say "cannot do" or they'll give you options and talk about a price. You don't have to accept their price. You are not being held prisoner /

Comment: @WeatherVane sure, I just don't want to waste their time and then buy elsewhere. But they are probably not making much on the tires anyway.

Comment: You might actually buy the tyres there. You might discover it's a shop you want to do more business with. It's always worth challenging the price in some non-combative way, such as 'do you have any discounts available'? Or 'I'm sure I've seen them cheaper'. You are perfectly entitled to shop around for the best deal. Nobody is going to make a loss from it. You only become a time-waster if you place an order and later cancel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> save the 20% VAT when ordering from other EU country.

You can't, VAT is EU-wide.

Even if you buy in another EU or EFTA (Iceland, Switzerland, Lichtenstein and Norway) country, the only case when you are exempt from it, is when you are a VAT-registered business, and even then it's convoluted (you may need to pay it anyway).

This would be different if you were outside of the EU of course

> Can I get tires with different parameters or does it have to be exactly this?

Look at your owners manual or around the door area for a sticker, all the tire sizes that will fit your car and are recommended by the manufacturer (unless you have third-party rims of course) are there, and you should follow it

You absolutely need to follow the first three numbers (265/55 R19) since it is the actual sizing of the tire, the last 4 character are the wiggle room :

- 109 : the load bearing capacity of the tire (see conversion chart [here](https://www.goodyear.com/en_US/learn/tire-basics/tire-load-index.html), 109 meaning 2271 lbs or 1030kg)
- V : the [rated speed](https://www.pirelli.com/tires/en-us/car/driving-and-tire-tips/how-to-read/tire-speed-rating) the tire can endure (V = 149mph = 240km/h)

You may find other tires with differing load bearing and rated speed but you need to make sure not to underspec either ratings else it's a really bad safety risk (tire blowing out...)

A retailer in my country does seems to have real winter tires in 109V (Pirelli mostly), or in 113H (Michelin mostly)

> Also very confusing, some have the right size, rated mud and snow but are classified as summer tires?

M+S means it's a 4-seasons tires, so it is a summer tire in a way, it can be used in winter condition, but it is not a proper winter tire.

Comment: Yes, I have a business, I do this frequently, its pretty simple actually. So no way around the first 3 numbers? I thought only the wheel diameter was set in stone.